# Circular errors in submission between not having permission and ERROR ITMS-90121

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, submission

When I was trying to submit my application in Xcode 6, I got the following error:

ERROR ITMS-90121: “This bundle is invalid. The executable name, as reported by CFBundleExecutable in the info.plist file may not contain these characters: \ [ ] { } parenthesis . + *”

So, I went and changed the default executable name, ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}, to the apps name (all letters and no spaces). When I did this, I got the following error when I tried to run the app on my phone or a simulator:

“The file “app name” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.”

And the app will not run on my phone and I can’t submit it. I looked for help on how to help this and all I could find is to change the executable name to ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} for Xcode 6 and it will work.

However, when I do this, I get my original error… It is as if I am stuck in a never ending error circle I can’t get out of. Other things I have tried:

(1) Deleting the derived data in the organizer
(2) Restarting Xcode
(3) Restarting my computer and phone
(4) Keeping the default executable name without the symbols

My app is finished I’m just running into this one error in the submission that I can’t seem to find a way around. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The issue is your .app contains one of those symbols. Changing the executable name in your info.plist won't fix it, since that's the name Xcode looks for to run the app, but your build product still has the symbol in the name (you can verify this by checking the Products group in your Xcode project). I'm running into the same issue with my project; I'll let you know when I find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `PRODUCT_NAME` should not contain any of these characters: `\ [ ] { } parenthesis . + *`. If you want your application to have a name that does though, edit the Bundle Display Name and Bundle Name of your `info.plist`.

Changing your `PRODUCT_NAME` to contain just letters and no spaces, while updating the app's name in your plist should fix the issue.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1823/_index.html)

Comment: Thanks it worked! I had a : symbol that stopped it from working

Comment: Excellent! Make sure to mark this answer as correct if the solution worked for you.

Comment: excuse me I didn't understand what should I do.. I have the same error submitting the app because the app has  * in the name, what should I do in order to keep the * and still be able to submit the app?

Comment: You need to update your PRODUCT_NAME in your project's build settings to not contain the *. If you still want the star in your app's name, open your info.plist and update the Bundle Display Name and Bundle Name accordingly.